# Is there a default order when adding a limit?

Tags: postgresql

If I have many `todos` and they are associated with a `project`. When I run the following query what is the default order?

```
SELECT  "todos".* FROM "todos" WHERE "todos"."project_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["project_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

In most instances, it returns the last todo. I've also seen it return the first todo or another in between.

I know that by adding an order clause I can control which record is returned. I'm trying to understand the behavior of this particular query for troubleshooting purposes.

Comment: Short answer: there is no order.

Comment: So it's just how it is read off of the disk?

Comment: @NateBird Most databases are stored using linked lists or b-trees so it is the traversal order of those in most cases.  As you add, update, remove records that tree or list ordering might change.

Answer (score 1):

The ordering should be the same as when you do a `SELECT` without a `LIMIT`.  When dealing with SQL, order is not an inherent property of the data.  There are many activities that can change the ordering of the data and even different versions of a RDBMS can result in different ordering.

If you want a query to follow some sort of logical ordering you MUST use `ORDER BY`.

Comment: The reason I'm interested in the `LIMIT` is that it chooses one of the `todos`. The beginning of the array or the end?

Comment: Sorry, I had to downvote.There answer is:there is no order. (imagine a hash join, or whatever subquery join) THERE IS NO (guaranteed) ORDER. PERIOD.

Comment: @wildplasser That is literally what my answer says with a description of how most RDBMS's work on the back end to explain why.  If you want to downvote that is your choice, but your reasoning for it either stems from a misunderstanding of what I wrote or a lack of understanding of how most RDBMS store data.

Comment: `The ordering should be the same as when you do a SELECT without a LIMIT` Plain wrong. There is no order. period.

Comment: @wildplasser  Except that it isn't plain wrong, you are.  For a straight table dump like in this question, the RDBMS will traverse the linked list or b-tree.  When you do a `LIMIT X`, all it does is stop the traversal after X steps.  So now we've narrowed it down, your reasoning is based on a lack of understanding of how most RDBMS store data.

Comment: If you want me to get into the nitty gritty of how the heap files work with headers, pages, items, etc. I can, but it is hard to follow for most people.  What you're suggesting is that the heap file is rewritten on a simple `SELECT` which is bonkers and flat out wrong.